# RewriteRule does not work with trailing slash in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a RewriteRule in my .htaccess that works almost as I wanted.
What I want is a rule that works with an optional trailing slash.

```
foo.com/bar   > foo.com/index.php?p=bar
foo.com/bar/  > foo.com/index.php?p=bar
```

What I have is this;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.pdf)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index\.php\?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

But this doesn't seem to work when the trailing slash is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule to allow an optional trailing slash:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(png|jpe?g|gif|bmp|pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thnx for your answer! It did a little. The only problem is that now all images/files on the page that have a relative url, are not working anymore, because they refer to `foo.com/bar/image.jpg`

Comment: That is because of use of relative URLs. Add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Thnx! That did it.